# Why does Unity apply injection behavior when resolving class registered as implementation of some interface

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container, interception

I register dependency like this:

```
this.Container.RegisterType<IFoo, Foo>(
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>(), new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>());
```

this works fine. 
However when I resolve `Foo` instead of `IFoo` I get error:

> ArgumentException - Type passed must be an interface.

It looks like Unity still tries to apply `InterfaceInterceptor` to this dependency. But why?